# Lexical, Syntactical, or Semantic Error differences in Java

Tags: java, syntax, semantics, lexical-analysis

I'm practicing lexical, syntactical, and semantic differences (using Java language). For the set below I wanted to identify if they are lexical, syntactical, or semantic errors. Just wanted to make sure I am doing them right and wanted some feedback.

```
a) double if;             Syntactical Error
b) doif (1 ==1);          Syntactical Error
c) x12 = “x12”;           Semantic Error
d) int double = 1.0;      Syntactical Error
e) 0-;                    Syntactical Error
f) int a = 09 – 90;       Syntactical Error
g) int $10 = 10;          No Error
h) char $dollar = ‘$’;    No Error
```

I feel like I am missing something in the last two. I checked using Eclipse though and it is not showing any errors. Is it really "no error"?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: b) is No Error if you've defined a function somewhere called doif that takes a boolean

Comment: Can you please explain to me why a) in your code has syntactical error? As per my understanding syntax analyzer does not determine token is valid or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"No error" is indeed correct. The dollar sign [is permissible in -- including at the start of -- Java identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) (although the JLS recommends that it's only used in mechanically-generated code or to access pre-existing names on legacy systems).

Answer (score 1):

int a = 09-90;

**Lexical Error** Octal numbers starts with zero and can use digits from 0-7. Hence, 09 is neither an octal nor an integer. So, it is not a Token in JAVA. And, anything which is not a token in java comes under lexical error.

doif (1 ==1);

**Semantic Error** doif is a perfect identifier(function name) and we are passing it here (1==1) which is TRUE value. Hence, this example follows the syntax of 'function call'. But, problem here is that doif function is not defined before its use. Uninitialized use of identifier causes Semantic Error. Hence, given example is a type of Semantic Error.

Answer (score 0):

For any language Lexical, Syntactical, or Semantic Error can be like below

Lexical Analysis - Check for all token exist in a language or not.
e.g. 
`foo a=1;`
 foo is not a token/keyword in java so lexical error.

Syntactical Analysis - Check that all statement are according to grammar rules.
e.g. `int 1a=0;`  No lexical error but syntactical error.
Does not follow grammar rules for naming a identifier.

Semantic Analysis - check that statement make sense or not.
e.g. `int a=1/0;` No lexical, Syntactical error but semantic error.
As Division by Zero is not possible.

Hope this helps.